# Clustering data sets with multiple variables

Tags: cluster-analysis, machine-learning

I am learning how to cluster large datasets and this maybe a newbie question, but I haven’t found a suitable answer in the Documentation or on this board.

My question is best illustrated by an example. Let’s import some data:

```
irisData = Import["http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/data/iris.csv", "CSV”];
(*Column labels *)
pLabels = {"Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Type”};
```

How do I construct clusters based on only two columns say “Sepal.Length” and “Sepal.Width” and still retain the rest of the data… as part of the clusters

Ideally I would like a function:

```
  findClusters[data,n,columnlist]
```

that would cluster the *data* into *n* clusters using the data in the *columnlist* such that output data format of the clusters is the same as the input data.

I can find the clusters and plot them as:

```
clusters = {cluster1, cluster2, cluster3} = FindClusters[irisData[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 3];
ListPlot[{{#1, #2} & @@@ cluster1, {#1, #2} & @@@ cluster2, {#1, #2} & @@@ cluster3}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200, FrameLabel -> pLabels[[1 ;; 2]]]
```

But I’d like to use the clusters that I found using FindClusters above to explore say “Sepal.Length” vs “Petal.Width” or some other data analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use one of the syntax options for `FindClusters` involving rules. When clustering your dataset, transform it to `{data to cluster} -> {data to return}` format at the level of either individual elements or the whole list. The details are explained in the documentation.

For example, to cluster on columns 1 (sepal length) and 4 (petal width):

```
irisData = Import["http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/data/iris.csv", "CSV"];
sample = irisData[[All, {1, 4}]] -> irisData;
sample[[All, 1]]
```

> {5.1, 0.2} -> {5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, "setosa"}

Then of course

```
FindClusters[sample];
% // Length
```

> 3

```
%%[[1, 1]]
```

> {5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, "setosa"}

Comment: This works well. Thanks for taking time out to post!

Answer (score 3):

This is based on mfvonh’s answer. I thought I would flush out the full answer for posterity.

Let’s cluster the data based on Sepal Length and Sepal Width

```
 sample = irisData[[All, {1, 2}]] -> irisData;
 clusters = {cluster1, cluster2, cluster3} = FindClusters[sample, 3];
```

Let’s plot the various characteristics of the clusters:

```
{ListPlot[({#1, #2} &  @@@ clusters[[#]]) & /@ Range[3], 
FrameLabel -> pLabels[[1 ;; 2]] ]
, ListPlot[({#2, #3} &  @@@ clusters[[#]]) & /@ Range[3], 
FrameLabel -> pLabels[[2 ;; 3]] ]} // List // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
pLabels = {"Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Type"};

IrisPlot[x_, y_] :=
 ListPlot[FindClusters[irisData[[All, {x, y}]], 3],
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> pLabels[[{x, y}]]]

IrisPlot[2, 3]
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to cluster using Petal Length and Petal Width fields, but for the clusters that I’ve computed plot the the Petal Length vs Sepal Width…